# How to store data after window.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below I have a vehicle dropdown that will pull the new options from text files. I have yet to find a way to save those selected TEXT values after the page changes to the correct category page. So ultimately I changed the dropdown into a div that will display the selected dropdown as text.

So how do I either..

A. keep the dropdown values and text values after the page reloads.

B. keep the selected text and proper div displays

Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="shop_vehicle_container">
    <div id="shop_vehicle">
        <div id="bl_firstRow">                    
                   <div id="vehic_sel">
                   <div class="sel_label">
                    <div class="sel_label">
                        Shop By Vehicle:
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="sel_container">
                     <select id="vehic_sel_model">
                        <option value="">Choose Model</option>
                        <option value="17Prelude">Prelude</option>
                        <option value="21Civic">Civic</option>
                        <option value="22CRX">CRX</option>
                        <option value="23CivicdelSol">Civic del Sol</option>
                        <option value="18Accord">Accord</option>
                        <option value="20Odyssey">Odyssey</option>
                        <option value="24Element">Element</option>
                        <option value="26Pilot">Pilot</option>
                        <option value="16Passport">Passport</option>
                        <option value="15CR-V">CR-V</option>
                        <option value="19S2000">S2000</option>
                        <option value="25Insight">Insight</option>
                        <option value="29Accord Crosstour">Accord Crosstour</option>
                        <option value="31Crosstour">Crosstour</option>
                        <option value="30CR-Z">CR-Z</option>
                        <option value="27Ridgeline">Ridgeline</option>
                        <option value="28Fit">Fit</option>
                    </select>
                    <select disabled ="" id="vehic_sel_year">
                    <option value="">Choose Year</option>
                    </select>   
                    <select disabled= "" id="vehic_sel_trim" onchange="VehicPaste()">
                        <option value="">Choose Trim Level</option>
                    </select>
<script src="/v/js.js"></script>    
<script src="/v/Fade to New DIv.js"></script>
<script src="/v/OpenSecondRow.js"></script>
<script>
function VehicPaste() {
    var Vehicle =document.getElementById('vehic_sel_model').options[document.getElementById('vehic_sel_model').selectedIndex].text + " "+document.getElementById('vehic_sel_year').options[document.getElementById('vehic_sel_year').selectedIndex].text+ " "+ document.getElementById('vehic_sel_trim').options[document.getElementById('vehic_sel_trim').selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("VehicleMessage").innerHTML = "Honda " + Vehicle;
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="vehic_submit" style= "display: none">
<div id="VehicleMessage"></div>
<input id = "changeVehic" type="image" src="/v/changevehicle_btn.gif.png">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeVehic").click(function(){
       $('#vehic_submit').fadeOut(0, function() {
            $('#bl_firstRow').html($('#bl_firstRow').html());
            $('#bl_firstRow').fadeIn(0);
        });
    })
});
</script>
                        </div>
            <div class="clearfloat">
            </div>
<br>
        <div id="bl_secondRow" style="display:none">
            <div id="vehic_sel2">
                <div class="sel_label">
                    <div class="sel_label">
                        Shop By Category:
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="sel_container">
                    <select id="vehic_sel_section">
                        <option value="">Choose Engine</option>
                    </select>
<script>
    $(function goto(){
      $('#vehic_sel_section').on('change', function () {
          var url = "/SearchResults.asp?Cat="+document.getElementById('vehic_sel_section').value
          if (url) { 
              window.location = url; 
}
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: you should check `localStorage` you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: @ParthTrivedi and you should make that an answer!

Comment: You can also add the data to the url as #hastag if you want better browser support or as ?parameter if you don't mind using server side code.

Comment: Or you can decode a ?parameter client side with a custom written function (Sadly no built in js support...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change` event of `<select>` you can `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('select_vehic_sel_model', JSON.stringify($(this).val()));
```

and on `DOM` ready you can get it back as

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('select_vehic_sel_model');

if(retrievedObject!=undefined && retrievedObject!=null){
   $("#vehic_sel_model").val(retrievedObject);
}
```

You can make `json` object if you are having more items like

```
var json = {
"select_vehic_sel_model":"<value>",
"textbox":"<value>",
"div_status":"hide",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several options available to you as some already noted in the comments.

1. Use `localStorage` to save bits of data you need across page loads that are accessible locally (hence the name :p).  You can read more about it on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
2. Use query parameters in the URL, so tag `?item1=val1&item2=val2` or some variation of it.
3. Use the hash tag to append data similarly to number 2, but it doesn't actually get sent to the server.  Example: `#item1=asdasd,item2=valasd2`.

You can also stringify an object and store the JSON in the URL, etc.